# Remote Database Access Hosts - Wild Cards

Tags: mysql, database, remote-server

I'm trying to enable my computer to remotely access a MySQL database.

The website is not letting me enter the IP address as is, so I need to start the address with a % wildcard.(Reasons to do with restrictions on free hosting).

IP: 192.168.0.78

Remote Access: %.168.0.%

Will that setting allow my IP to connect to the database?

Comment: Hi, 192.168.*.* is a local network. If your remote mysql server is not in your network you have to provide it your external IP (http://www.whatismyip.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

192.**** is your IP within your personal network at home.

Go to http://www.whatsmyip.org/.  Find what your IP is and go from there.

As for the wildcard charater, I've never tried it, but it seems logically correct.  But do try it with the correct IP.